# Categorizing saddle points of real multivariate polynomials

Tags: critical-point-theory

I have a multivariate polynomial function of N variables

$f(x_1,x_2,…,x_N) = x_1 x_2 x_3 .. x_N \left( 1 + \sum_i^N (a_i x_i^2  - x_i) \right)$,

where $a_i > 0$ are real positive numbers.

By Bezout's theorem, this has $2^N$ critical points, which may be complex.

I'm interested in the critical points for real positive $x_i$, so there are at most $2^N$ of them, but there may be fewer.

Here's my question:

Can I make a stronger statement? That there are at most one minimum, at most N one-negative mode saddle points, at most $N$-choose-$2$ two-negative mode saddle points, etc.?

Comment: What does 'categorizing' mean in your title? and what's the relation of your question to algebraic topology?

Comment: By "categorizing" I meant categorizing the critical points by their number of negative modes, as in the final sentence of my question. I want to know whether it is possible to bound not just the total number of saddle points, but the number of saddle points with a given number of negative modes.

Comment: I've changed the tag to "critical-point-theory".